# Can I remove all ID naming with same character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For instance , there is a

img id = img_1   , img_2 , img_3 , img_4 and so on..

However, I don't know the exact number of divs

```
$('#img_').remove
```

seems not working

So , How to remove all the img that has an id "img_"? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the attribute starts with selector to grab the elements you want:

```
$('[id^="img_"]').remove();
```

#### [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Thanks ! exactly what I want

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this should work:

```
$('[id^=img_]').remove();
```

It removes any element with an `id` *that starts with* `img_`

Answer (score 0):

Apply same class to all images which has an id `"img_"`  then use

```
$('.className').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help:

```
for( var i = 0; i < $('img').length; i++) {
    if( $($('img')[i]).attr('id').indexOf('img_') !== -1 ) {
        $($('img')[i]).remove();
    }
}
```